# Convert nvarchar to Date type with one line of command

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column `Number_Calc` with data type of `nvarchar(50)` and the data in this column contains information of `yyyymmdd`. Below is the screenshot of the sample data of the said column.

[image: Number_Calc Column]

For example the first row contain this number `F**20190531**1632824`. `20190531` is actually the year (`2019`) month (`05`) and date (`31`).

Now, I'd like to update my dataset and add a new column called `Submission_Date` of datatype `date` in this format `"yyyy-mm-dd"`. I am able to do this by creating a column called `Submission_Date_0` and extract 8 characters from the string after the first character "F", after that only generated the desired column `Submission_Date`. I am using two commands to get this done as per the following:

```
update Table1 
set Submission_Date_0 = substring(Number_Calc, patindex('%[0-9]%', Number_Calc), 8);
```

and from here I get the data in the following format:

[image: Submission_Date_0]

Then, I use the following command to convert the data type to the desired data type for the column `Submission_Date`:

```
update Table1 
set Submission_Date = convert(nvarchar, Submission_Date_0, 103) ;
```

And, I get the desired column in the format needed as per the below example:

[image: Submission_Date]

I know this can be done in much simpler way in SQL with one line of code. However, I am not able to figure it out. Could anyone please help me on this?

Thank you.

Comment: please don't post image. Post the data as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly write your these query in single query as

```
 update Table1
     set Submission_Date = convert(nvarchar(255),
                                   substring(Number_Calc, patindex('%[0-9]%', Number_Calc), 8),
                                   103
                                  ) ;
```

Comment: . . You should format your code so I at least can upvote it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: please check